# How to add values to Firebase Firestore without overwriting?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have two Activities, I am adding data to Firestore from these two activities individually. But, whenever I add second activity data to Firestore, it is overwriting the first activity data. I used below code in the two activities:

```
 firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).set(data)
```

How to stop overwriting? I want to save both Activities data in the same `user_id`.

Comment: Add one more child for each activity below `user_id`

Comment: How to add child. would you tell me..@Dumbo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to add one more document or collection that it will be able to store more just one data values for single user.
You can create a document references for both activities:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id+"/acitivity1").set(data);
//and  
firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id+"/acitivity2").set(data);
```

Or you can create a sub-collection for it:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id)
                  .collection("Activities").document("acitivity1").set(data);
//and
firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id)
                  .collection("Activities").document("acitivity2").set(data);
```

More about hierarchical data [there](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#hierarchical-data).

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways in which you can achieve this. First one would be to use a `Map`:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("yourProperty", "yourValue");
firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).update(map);
```

As you can see, I have used `update()` method instead of `set()` method.

The second approach would be to use an object of your model class like this:

```
YourModelClass yourModelClass = new YourModelClass();
yourModelClass.setProperty("yourValue");
firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id)
    .set(yourModelClass, SetOptions.mergeFields("yourProperty"));
```

As you can see, I have used the `set()` method but I have passed as the second argument `SetOptions.mergeFields("yourProperty")`, which means that we do an update only on a specific field.

Comment: Have you achieved to update a value without overwriting?

Comment: ....I got it,, But i faced another problem a little later. I used a ScrollView in my Layout. But it is not scrolling the full content. After scrolling, it still leaves some scrollable portion at the bottom. And it formed small unusual white space at the bottom of the screen. how can i solve it

Comment: This is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Comment: I am a beginner in android programming... I don't even know how to use Model classes. So, I have not tried it. But, I liked the answer you posted for my previous question about Switch statement and Chechboxes usage. It was very helpful. That is why I asked you another question in the comments section.

Comment: You're beginner, I understand but that is how you solved your actual problem, by adding a new document/collection? I'm happy to hear that the problem regarding the switch statement helped you.

Comment: Yes, I added new Document and Collection in two activities. it worked

Comment: In this case, your question is wrong. You have asked how `to stop overriding` in terms of updating a document but you ended up solving this problem by creating new documents. Is that realy what you wanted?

Comment: I want to add two Activities results under one Document. Of course, I did not achieve what i wanted. Anyway, I ended up creating separate documents for both. I settled for the less.

Comment: If somebody needs to know about following scenarios: First example works perfect if the field already exist. Second example works perfect if the field doesn't exist yet.

Comment: but what if "yourProperty" mentioned here is a arraylist and I only want to append to it?

Comment: @NadeemShaikh In that case, please check the docs regarding [update elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Comment: I have gone through that. But my question is what will happen if I directly call the update function as mentioned over there without checking document exists or not?

Comment: @NadeemShaikh I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63335716/how-to-create-array-if-not-already-present-and-then-append-data-to-the-array-in/63337452#63337452) might help.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the user document allready exists in firestore then you should use

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).update(data)
```

If you don't know if the document exists then you can use

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).set(data, {merge:true})
```

This performs a deep merge of the data

Alternatively you can do it by using subcollections

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation, you could use as a second parameter `{merge:true}`, in my experience the problem usually is in the fact that you are trying to store different data but with the same key.

Even using `{merge: true}` will always update the current key with the value you are passing in.

Merge:true  Works only if the key does not exist already. I believe every key in a document must be unique.

To test it try to pass(keeping `{merge: true}` as the second parameter) data with a different key, it will merge to existing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a direct update

`db.collection('cities').doc('restaurants').update({
    rating:"3.2"
});`

Only the field rating is going to change, the rest of the fields will remain the same.

Lets say you have 3 fields, and want to change only 2 of them, you can also do this in a different way

```
// You get the document 'restaurants' and then do the below
db.collection('cities').doc('restaurants').get().then((doc) => {

    // Get the rating field string, parse it to a float, remove 0.4 from it and
    // set it to a tmp variable
    var tmpRating = parseFloat(doc.data()['rating']) - 0.4;

    // Get the array of strings field 'menu' and set it to a tmp variable
    var tmpMenu = doc.data()['menu'];

    // Push 'spaghetti' string to the tmp array of strings( Can also put an
    // adapting string variable instead of a specific string like 'spaghetti'
    tmpMenu.push('spaghetti');

    // Update only the specific fields 'rating' and 'menu' and keep the rest unchanged.
    db.collection('cities').doc(doc.id).update({
        rating: toString(tmpRating), // Don't forget to separate them by commas
        menu: tmpMenu
    });
});
```