# Adding new values with same keys to existing document in Firestore firebase without overwriting

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add data to the Firestore database without overwriting it. The data is in the format written below and has numerous other `"Question"` in the same format and I want to add this to just one document.

```
{
    "Question": String,
    "Answer": String,
}
```

The same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382675/how-to-add-values-to-firebase-firestore-without-overwriting) but it covers it in java and not in python. I have tried updating it and setting it but it has only been overwriting it.
Note that all of my `Questions` are elements in a list in this format:

```
['{\n "Question": String,\n "Answer":String \n}, ...]
```

What I am currently doing in my code is going through the array and performing the code below:

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u"Questions").document(u"ques")
doc_ref.update(questionsAnswers)
```

but this only leaves me with the last question added to the database.

Comment: Do you want to add in subcollection of Activities? and please post code you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Use the update method to change the contents of an existing document as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data).

```
city_ref = db.collection(u'your-collection').document(u'your-document')
city_ref.update({u'your-field': u'your-field-value'})
```

I suggest also using the [API documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/client.html).

Comment: sir i think he want to try to add new document each time user answer question

Comment: @Ashish The question says "add data to firestore database without overwriting it".  That sounds like an update.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am trying to add new data to an existing document, sorry for the confusion ill change the title

Comment: It's still an update as I'm showing here in my answer.

Comment: The problem is that my other data have the same keys so when i update it, it overwrites it and thus i end up with only the last question.

Comment: Please edit the question to be more clear about what the problem is.  You should explain what you want the document to look like **after** the operation is complete, and the code you tried that isn't working the way you expect.