# How to create array if not already present and then append data to the array in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Referring to ["Update elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array):

I can understand how to add elements to an **existing array**. But I would like to create a new array if doesn't already exist and then add data to it in a single Firestore call. How to do that?

1. **Doesn't add data if an array is not present.**

   `.update("arrayName", FieldValue.arrayUnion("arrayData"))`
2. **Creates a new array if not present and adds data, but the data is overwritten not appended.**

   `.set(hashMapOf("arrayName" to arrayListOf("arrayData")), SetOptions.merge())`

I want to make a **single** Firestore call,

1. Which checks if an array is present if not creates a new array.
2. Then it checks if the data is present in the array if not adds the data to the array.

Is there a straightforward solution to this or do we have to make more than one call to achieve this?

**Edit:**

**The code I am using:**

```
return firebaseFirestore
  .collection("collection1")
  .document("document1")
  .collection("collection2")
  .document("document2")
  .update("arrayName", FieldValue.arrayUnion("arrayData"))
```

@Alex as you pointed out, the array is created if not present, and data is added to it.
Found my problem to be caused due to a different issue.

In my scenario, the "collection1", "document1", "collection2" and "document2" were not already created. My code works only if the document to which the array is to be added ("document") is already created.

Can you help me in solving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Doesn't add data if an array is not present.

Yes, it does. According to the official documentation regarding FieldValue's [arrayUnion()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#arrayUnion(java.lang.Object...)) method:

> Returns a special value that can be used with `set()` or `update()` that tells the server to union the given elements with any array value that already exists on the server. Each specified element that doesn't already exist in the array will be added to the end. If the field being modified is not already an array it will be overwritten with an array containing exactly the specified elements.

In other words, if your `arrayName` property is not an array, your `arrayData` will be added to an array and then that array will be overwritten in the document. So if your `arrayName` is not an array, it will become an array. If the property does **not** exist at all, a new array will be created and it will be added to the document. So if your document looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- firstCollection
          |
          --- firstDocument
               |
               --- docName: "Doc Name"
```

After using these lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference docRef = rootRef.collection("firstCollection").document("firstCollection");
docRef.update("arrayName", FieldValue.arrayUnion("arrayData"));
```

Your document will look like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- firstCollection
          |
          --- firstDocument
               |
               --- docName: "Doc Name"
               |
               --- arrayName: ["arrayData"]
```

**Edit:**

> My code works only if the document to which the array is to be added ("document") is already created.

Yes, that's the expected behavior. You **cannot** update an array in a document that does not exist. To solve this, you should basically create that document, with at least a property so it exists at that particular location. The property might be an empty array or any other [supported data-type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), as it will be converted later into an array.

A more appropriate solution might be to check if the document exists. If it exists, add it with the desired array, otherwise, update it. But there is no way you can do that in a single go.

Comment: Have edited my question. Can you please check that.